# .NET C# PrintDocument is very slow with Dot Matrix Printer

Tags: c#, .net, printing, printdocument, dot-matrix

I have a problem with my c# application, because i need to print with dot matrix printer "Olivetti PR2 Plus" using X and Y Position coordinates, like VB6 did. the problem is if the string have more than 20 characters aprox, the printer is very slow and i need to print fast.

I have the following code for testing purposes and have the problem.

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Document = new PrintDocument();            
        Document.PrintPage += Document_PrintPage;
        Document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = ((ICollection)PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters).OfType<string>().Where(p => p.ToUpper().Contains("OLIVETTI")).First().ToString();        
        Document.Print();
    }

private void Document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("asdfasdfasdfasdasdffasdfasdfasdf", new Font("Consolas", 8), Brushes.Black, 20, 0, new StringFormat());
            e.Graphics.DrawString("asdfasdfasdasdaasdfsdfffasdfasdf", new Font("Consolas", 8), Brushes.Black, 20, 10, new StringFormat());
            e.Graphics.DrawString("asdfasdfaasdfsasdfsadfdfasdfasdf", new Font("Consolas", 8), Brushes.Black, 20, 20, new StringFormat());
            e.Graphics.DrawString("asfdasdfsadfasasdfasdfdasdfasdff", new Font("Consolas", 8), Brushes.Black, 20, 30, new StringFormat());
            e.Graphics.DrawString("asfdasdsdafasadfsasdfdasdfasdfff", new Font("Consolas", 8), Brushes.Black, 20, 40, new StringFormat());
            e.Graphics.DrawString("asdfaasdsadfsadffsadfsdassadfdff", new Font("Consolas", 8), Brushes.Black, 20, 50, new StringFormat());
            e.Graphics.DrawString("asfdasdfsdafsadfsadfasasasdfdfdf", new Font("Consolas", 8), Brushes.Black, 20, 60, new StringFormat());
            e.Graphics.DrawString("asdfasadfassadfdfssadfassadfdfdf", new Font("Consolas", 8), Brushes.Black, 20, 70, new StringFormat());
            e.Graphics.DrawString("asfdasadfasadfsdfssadasasdffdfdf", new Font("Consolas", 8), Brushes.Black, 20, 80, new StringFormat());   
        }
```

I can't print in RAW "DOS" mode because the source of the data to print have specific coordinates for match with the paper formats. ¿any sugestion to improve the perfomance of the printer?

Comment: Define 'very slow'… It's been a long time since I worked with a dot matrix printer but in general, they are quite slow when it comes to printing graphics. If you know which emulation the printer supports (most dot matrix printers support Epson codes), you can do fine-grained positioning even in text mode. Google is your friend!

Comment: the thing is in VB6 the printer goes fast "3 lines with 70 characters each one" in 1 second max.. with this code the same scenario expends 3 or 4 seconds..

Comment: Is that running on the same system? Please share the VB6 code so it can be compared to the C# code.

Comment: '"3 lines with 70 characters each one" in 1 second max' sounds like printing in text mode, though. If you could post a short video of that (no need to be able to read the lines), the movement of print head and paper should allow one to see whether it is text or graphics mode.

Comment: Hello!. I found if a print in Draft font "with vb6" the printer is fast even if i print with X Y coordinates, when i change the font to any other wich isn't Draft the printer is slow too.
.NET "Font" object work with current installed windows fonts like "TrueType fonts" and others, the problem is in VB6 i can set the FontName to "Draft (10 cpi)" and printer resolve the font if Windows does not have it, but in .NET this property is readonly "get;" and does not allow to set any font what windows doesn't have it.

Any suggestions to print in Printer default font's with .net?

Comment: If the VB6 code lets the printer use a font "Draft (10 cpi)" it means the printer prints in text mode. Your code causes the printer to print in graphics mode. Some suggestions for printing in text mode can be found here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ab39ba9-ad67-43fb-aa49-0309c15ed635/printing-text-directly-to-a-printer-not-as-a-graphic?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: thanks for your reply, that means vb6 print in text mode even if I define coordinates by "CurrentX and CurrentY" properties in printer?, because vb6 let me use "Draft (10 cpi)" and .NET does not let me use a font in bitmap, like Draft or original "Courier"